# Printer service not found on port 515

Tags: printing

For services list on my Ubuntu, Printer service not found on port 515.

```
nmap -sT -O localhost

PORT     STATE SERVICE
23/tcp   open  telnet
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open  ipp
9050/tcp open  tor-socks
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 3.12 - 3.19, Linux 3.8 - 3.19
```

---

[image]

There is no Printer service on port 515. How to add Printer service on port 515?

---

```
nmap -v -p 515 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-11-19 13:03 IRST
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 13:03
Scanning localhost (127.0.0.1) [1 port]
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 13:03, 0.21s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000065s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
515/tcp closed printer
```

Comment: Tell us what actual problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: *Stop asking the same question repeatedly.*  There are now three (closed) copies of this question already - please do not repost the same question multiple times.  The other three copies of your question are now closed as duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Port `515/tcp` is the `line printer spooler` port. You could run a print spooler to listen to port 515, but....

The modern, Ubuntu way is to use CUPS (Common Unix Printing System), which listens to the Internet Printing Protocol on port `631/tcp`. Read `man cups`. Administer CUPS with a browser pointer to `http://localhost:631`

And, an easier way to see what's listening (or not) to a port is with `lsof` (and you get more information):

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:515 -i tcp:631
[sudo] password for w3: 
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
cupsd   17693 root   10u  IPv4 4833522      0t0  TCP *:ipp (LISTEN)
cupsd   17693 root   11u  IPv6 4833523      0t0  TCP *:ipp (LISTEN)
```